# For those wanting to study theoretical computer science, is Math a degree that worth more than Computer Science?

Tags: soft-question, computer-science, career-development

At my University, everyone first enrol in a Science and Technology, a very general course, and then choose the specialisation (like Computer Science, Math, some Engineering, etc).

As I was finishing the S&T course, I began to do Computer Science subjects - in fact, that was my intention since High School.

After doing Theory of Computation, I became fascinated with the subject. I like also subjects like foundations of Math and Logic.

I do like CS, but I don't really enjoy the fact that in the CS course we have to understand many constraints and search an efficient algorithm for the desired task. I prefer the world of Math, where one can deal with "infinite objects" without caring about physical limitations. By the way, regarding Theory of Computation, I liked computability far more than complexity, for example.

CS has too many subjects that, in my perception, don't really increase my understanding of the theoretical side of CS. For example: computer graphics, databases, software engineering, computer networks, security, distributed systems. All of these subjects are mandatory in the CS course of my university!

It seems to me that studying Math would give me more interesting tools to help me with my areas of interest and even the Math subjects that are not directly related to the field would train my Math ability, presenting me new ideas that could help me with proofs.

**So my question is: For those wanting to study theoretical computer science and related fields, is Math a degree that worth more than Computer Science?**

For those who think that the answer is positive, I would like to know why it is not a common path for people interested in theoretical CS. Maybe just the problem of leaving a course to enrol in another?

Comment: Theoretical computer science is basically math, so I think almost any undergrad math course would be useful for graduate study in TCS.  I don't know if a math degree would be worth "more", though.  You could always double major.  I would think it wouldn't be too hard to enter a grad program in TCS with a math degree if you have some TCS background too.  It's not my area though, so maybe someone in CS can answer.